# MySQL WHERE третий символ в строке единица

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется VARCHAR столбец SETTINGS и состоит из чисел - 03040123050392
Возможно сделать запрос - "WHERE третье число в строке равна единице" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не тестировал, но должно сработать

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(column_name, 3, 1) = '1'
```

Фактически это говорит "взять один символ, начиная с третьего в строке, и проверить его на соответствие единице".

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё получилось!